# How to implement serde's Serialize and Deserialize traits for an external type?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for an external enum and I have no idea how. It has `From<u64>` so all I want to do is just have that object serialize with that.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ImageBinds {
    binds: HashMap<KeybdKey, Vec<u8>>, // KeybdKey doesn't implement serialize
}

// won't compile with this:
// only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
// impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
// I understand the orphan rule and all that but I have no idea how else I'd implement it
// I've looked at serde remote stuff and I cannot work out how to do it with an enum without
// literally just copying the whole crate into my scope which is stupid
impl Serialize for KeybdKey {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        serializer.serialize_u64(u64::from(*self))
    }
}
```

[`KeybdKey`](https://docs.rs/inputbot/0.5.0/inputbot/enum.KeybdKey.html) is from the `inputbot` crate.

Comment: Does [this tutorial](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html) help?

Comment: I would be helpful to include the exact error and, even better, a reproducible case in a Rust Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/

Comment: The remote derive feature will not help you if your type is nested inside a `HashMap`. You either need a custom deserialize for the `HashMap` (i.e., `with` attribute), a wrapper type, or you try the [`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.8.0/serde_with/guide/serde_as/index.html#using-serde_as-on-types-without-serializeas-and-serialize-implementations) crate.  

The documentation only mentions `From<KeybdKey> for u64` but not a `From<u64>`. So this will only allow you to write the serialization code, but not the deserialization.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is with the [`Newtype` pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html). By wrapping the external type in a `Newtype`, you can implement a trait for it.

Your example will work with the following:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ImageBinds {
    binds: HashMap<MyKeybdKey, Vec<u8>>,
}

// This is a Newtype containing the external type .
struct MyKeybdKey(KeybdKey);

impl Serialize for MyKeybdKey {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        serializer.serialize_u64(u64::from(self.0))
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyKeybdKey {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        // ...deserialize implementation.
    }
}
```

I didn't fill in the `Deserialize` implementation, because it will be rather long, but the basic concept is to just reverse the `From` implementation you relied on in the `Serialize` implementation.